# How to use Resource file values in javascript asp.net form applications

Tags: javascript, asp.net

How to use Resource file values in javascript asp.net form applications.
I have a folder called Resources inside that I have TestResources.resx file. There I want to get ErrorMessage value.
I have written below code inside  but nothing returned.

```
var alertValue=@TestResources.ErrorMessage;
alert(alertValue);
```

Comment: You could create a handler that replaces the values of your file.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use ASP.NET Resource strings from within javascript files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/940769/use-asp-net-resource-strings-from-within-javascript-files)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an HTTP handler that replaces your dictionary keys with the actual values. Remember that you would need to handle caching yourself.

Here's an example: http://madskristensen.net/post/localize-text-in-javascript-files-in-aspnet