# How to get resource (.resx) string in JS file

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, multilingual

I am developing an application `MVC 5` in `multilingual` and I have some functions in my `xyz.js` file, but I don't know how to get resource string in `.js` file. I have explored a lot on web but not able to find suitable answer. Please help me out for this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Use ASP.NET Resource strings from within javascript files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/940769/use-asp-net-resource-strings-from-within-javascript-files)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved this problem. I have made a method in my controller which will get the resource string from resource file and I used that string further in my js file.

```
  public JsonResult GetResourceString(string labelName)
    {
        string result ="";
        result = ResourceMessage.ResourceManager.GetString(labelName);
        if (Request.Cookies["culture"].Value == "th")
        {
            cul = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("th"); 
             result = ResourceMessage.ResourceManager.GetString(labelName,cul);
        }
        return Json(new
        {
            message = result
        }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

Above method will get resource string and then you can use it.
Here `ResourceMessage` is my resource file name and cul is `CultuerInfo`.

Thanks :)